# javascript using or operator to iterate over list of strings

Tags: javascript, operators

I'm having trouble with the following piece of code:

```js
var fileheader = ["GENE_NAME", "3", "4", "1", "2", "logFC", "logCPM", "PValue", "FDR"]
for (var j = 0; j < fileheader.length; j++) {
  if (fileheader[j] !== ('GENE_NAME' || 'logCPM' || 'logFC' || 'FDR' || 'PValue')) {
    console.log(fileheader[j])
  }
}
```

I expected only the values "3","4","1", and "2" would be displayed, but instead they are all being displayed and I don't understand why.

Comment: All _except `GENE_NAME`_... there's your hint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's not how the `||` operator works. You'd have to write:

```
fileheader[j] !== 'GENE_NAME' || fileheader[j] !== 'logCPM' // ...etc
```

The other option is creating an array and using `indexOf`:

```
if (['GENE_NAME', 'logCPM', 'logFC', 'FOR', 'PValue'].indexOf(j) < 0) {
}
```

If you're only worried about newer browsers, you may also be able to get away with `includes` instead of `indexOf`.

Answer (score 6):

Try to write your code like,

```
var fileheader = ["GENE_NAME", "3", "4", "1", "2", "logFC", "logCPM", "PValue", "FDR"];
var filter = ['GENE_NAME', 'logCPM', 'logFC', 'FDR', 'PValue'];
for (var j=0; j<fileheader.length; j++){
    if (!filter.includes(fileheader[j])){
        console.log(fileheader[j])
    }
}
```

Note about using [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes),

It is a new installment to ES6, and it has limited browser support. It don't have support with IE even in recent versions. As an alternate to it you could use `Array.prototype.indexOf()`. Using it will give you the index of matched element, if nothing matches then it will return `-1`. Based on that you could modify your code.

Now lets come to the problem present in your code,

Have a look at the snippet below,

```
('GENE_NAME'||'logCPM'||'logFC'||'FDR'||'PValue')
```

Would always be evaluated to `'GENE_NAME'`. So your code is very much similar to,

```
var fileheader = ["GENE_NAME", "3", "4", "1", "2", "logFC", "logCPM", "PValue", "FDR"]
for (var j=0; j<fileheader.length; j++){
    if (fileheader[j] !== 'GENE_NAME'){
        console.log(fileheader[j])
    }
}
```

Comment: Clever use of includes. However, I think it's worth mentioning that both IE and edge don't support it (yet :P). https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Comment: @briosheje Yeah was about to do it. Thanks for pointing it though.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to show only Numbers you can use `isNaN`:

```
var fileheader = ["GENE_NAME", "3", "4", "1", "2", "logFC", "logCPM", "PValue", "FDR"]
for (var j=0; j<fileheader.length; j++){
    if (!isNaN(fileheader[j])){
        console.log(fileheader[j])
    }
}
```

Comment: Good observation of X Y problem...

Answer (score 0):

Usually `||` is used to evaluate a sequence of conditions, expressions that evaluate to true/false, to some value or no value, or similar scenarios.

You can do cool things, if you use this to control the sequence of execution in eachs expressions return value, as it stops after the **first** **evaluation** to **true**.

It is called logical or, however it returns something different in JavaScript (EcmaScript). Apparently the first String in your sequence.
And the rest is obvious enough. All except the first are inequal an show up.

Here is the explanation:

> Logical operators are typically used with Boolean (logical) values;
> when they are, they return a Boolean value.  The && and || operators
> actually return the value of one of the specified operands, so if
> these operators are used with non-Boolean values, they may return a
> non-Boolean value. The logical operators are described in the
> following table.
>
> **Returns expr1 if it can be converted to true**; otherwise, returns
> expr2.

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Ausdruecke_und_Operatoren#Logical_operators

Comment: Of course you should use array.contains() or sth like this for your purpose ...

Comment: i dont care, what do you expect from a logical operator ? a string ?

Comment: I expect the first truthy value, which in this case is a string, so yes.