# Javascript shorthand to call method if object exists

Tags: javascript, object, methods, logical-operators, shorthand

I have a variable and if that variable is a object I would like to call a method on that object, if not I want to do nothing.

I'm wondering if there is any reason why I shouldn't do it like this.

```
var foo = null;

  ////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // some code that could change foo to a object
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////

 foo && foo.bar();
```

Comment: If you know what you are doing, there is not way you should not do it...

Comment: will foo be defined like that?

Comment: Foo starts off null but might be changed later from a click event.  Then on other click events I check to see if it is still null, if so then I do nothing, if not null then it was assigned an object and I want to call a method on that object.

Comment: @Rayon if we all knew exactly what we were doing then we wouldn't be on StackOverFlow

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: `foo.hasOwnProperty("bar") ? foo.bar : foo`

Comment: @cmac My point is if it is working as expected, get busy knowing how it does.. If you could make out, go for it as you can solve issues which may come in future regarding that.. If you fail to understand, go for less complex and readable version..

Comment: @Rayon Makes sense, thanks!  I was just asking because I always see the other ways like ((typeof foo === 'object') && foo.bar()) and don't really see it done like this foo && foo.bar(); ...  which is shorter, cleaner, and easy to understand.  So, I was just wondering if there was something I was missing or didn't know about.

Comment: @cmac There is nothing new in this pattern. More of falsey and operators understanding...

Comment: Not sure why the OP is being given a hard time here.  It's a reasonable question (possibly a dup, I guess).  I understand the question to be "will the expression throw an exception if foo is null, and (implicitly) what's the value of the expression?"  My answer would be:  "this expression works fine (and has a value of null) when foo is null, and it works fine (and has a value of the return value of bar()) when foo is an object that implements bar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quick answer is yes, `foo && foo.bar()` won't throw an exception if `foo` is `null`, and if `foo` is non-null, `bar()` will be evaluated, and it's value will be the value of the expression.

Longer answer is that any value can be interpreted as a boolean, in the sense that every value is either truthy or falsey, and that the boolean operators do short-circuit evaluation -- left to right, if we see a `false &&` or a `true ||`, there's no reason to carry on evaluating.

One last fact is that the value of boolean expression is the value of the expression where the short-circuit happened.

Answer (score 19):

With ES6, you can combine [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) with [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```
foo?.bar?.call()
```

If you want to pass arguments, keep in mind that the first one in call assigns `this` in function call

```js
var foo = {
  bar: function(x) { return x; }
};

first.value  = foo?.bar?.call(0,42); // 42
second.value = foo?.baz?.call(0,42); // undefined, no error
```

```html
<input id="first">
<input id="second">
```

Comment: Instead of using call you can just use optional chaining with function calls directly: `foo?.bar?.()`. This is not only shorter but also works better in Typescript as this gives you intellisense in contrast to using `call`.

Comment: It seems even that is not necessary (at least in Typescript) anymore. You can just do `foo?.bar()` and it will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign an object to `foo` and a property with a function.

```js
var foo;

foo = {};
foo.bar = function () {
    console.log('inside bar');
};

foo && foo.bar && foo.bar();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
((typeof foo === 'object') && foo.bar())
```

or

```
(!(typeof foo == 'object') || foo.bar())
```

If foo is of type object then execute.

See my answer here [javascript using or operator to iterate over list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38642434/javascript-using-or-operator-to-iterate-over-list-of-strings/38642514#38642514) aswell.

This is a "common" issue for unintended behavior, if some uses assignments inside such a sequence and forgets that evaluation stops in the `||` sequence after first true , or stops after first false in the `&&` .